# Internet Explorer disappears immediately after running

Tags: internet-explorer

When I launch Internet Explorer 8, the main window appears briefly then immediately disappears. So far I've tried:

- Reregistering IEProxy.dll
- Uninstalling/reinstalling IE
- Running with Add-ons disabled

Nothing has helped. This is on Vista Home Premium

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the Event Viewer? Have you run anti-virus scans?

You can also try to boot in Safe mode, to see if an installed product is causing the problem.

Another try is to check system integrity :
[How to Repair Windows 7 System Files with System File Checker](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html).

**EDIT**

You could also turn off temporarily any security software you have (anti-virus, firewall etc.).

This Microsoft Support article suggests some more solutions:
[When you start Internet Explorer, it opens, flashes, and then closes immediately](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/967896)

- **Reset Internet Explorer settings** :
  Control Panel / Internet Options / Advanced / Reset Internet Explorer Settings / Reset.
- **Internet Explorer troubleshooters in Windows 7** :
  Control Panel / System and Security / Find and Fix Problems / View All / Internet Explorer Performance / Next.

If these do not help, it would be useful to know more about your Windows version and computer.

Comment: Nothing in event viewer. MSSE anti-virus scan shows it's clean. Same behavior in safe mode.

Comment: Also, ran SFC. No issues reported

Comment: Does it happen in Safe mode?

Comment: Yes, same behavior in safe mode

Comment: See my edit above.

Comment: I've tried all those solutions (except Win7 troubleshooters - it's a Vista machine)

Comment: Mokubai has beaten me to the next suggestion. A very full tutorial with screenshots can be found [here](http://vistaultimate.windowsreinstall.com/repairstartup/repairstartup.htm). Remember backup!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a full DVD of Vista (not an upgrade disk or manufacturer "recovery" disk) you could try to do a "Repair Install" as per the instructions on [this](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/88236-repair-install-vista.html) site.  You'll need to either have a DVD with your current service pack level, which you can create by following [How to Create a Vista SP1 Slipstream Installation DVD](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/151606-vista-sp1-slipstream-installation-dvd.html) or [How to Slipstream Vista SP2](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/230249-sliptream-vista-sp2.html)

As always it is good to keep backups of anything important.

Taken from: http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/88236-repair-install-vista.html

As a aid, I'll list the key points here:

> 1. Insert the Vista DVD into the DVD drive while your current Vista is
>      running (do not boot from the install
>      disk!)
> 2. Click on "Install Now"
> 3. Click through the installer entering details as appropriate,
>      noting that you **SHOULD NOT** enter
>      your product key as it may break
>      activation of Vista which you will do
>      as a last step.
> 4. Continue through the setup, selecting the correct version of Vista
>      you are using and confirming the
>      warning.
> 5. Click the "Upgrade Now" button and wait for it to finish installing, this
>      should reinstall all Windows
>      components but leave all your
>      applications and data intact.
> 6. Wait for the install to finish and remove the DVD.
> 7. Check that everything is working now, if any files are missing then
>      check the folders "C:\Windows.old",
>      "C:\$INPLACE.~TR" and "C:\$WINDOWS.~Q"
>      otherwise carry on to step 8.
> 8. Run [Disk Cleanup](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/76073-disk-cleanup.html) to check for and remove files listed as "Files
>      discarded by Windows upgrade"
> 9. Reactivate Vista by going to the Control Panel, System panel, scrolling
>      to the bottom and clicking "Activate
>      Windows Now"

Hopefully this would repair IE and restore everything it needs to work.